# Is there something special to consider when starting Shark in Snow Leopard?

Tags: iphone, shark

After upgrade to Snow Leopard and downloading the new Xcode along with all new developer tools, Shark does not start. I launch it but it never appears. Is this a known issue? Is there a solution to get it running?

Comment: I take it you figured out what was wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616548/is-there-a-quick-guide-on-how-to-use-shark-with-iphone-to-measure-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in system.log in Console.app?  Could be a clue there.
Also check for crash reports in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter.

Comment: Thanks. I had just deleted all CHUD tools and reinstalled them. Then it worked.